# Accessing dynamically allocated arrays on device (without passing them as kernel arguments)

Tags: memory-management, cuda, gpu, nvidia

How can an array of structs that has been dynamically allocated on the **host** be used by a kernel, **without passing the array of structs as a kernel argument?** This seems like a common procedure with a good amount of documentation online, yet it doesn't work on the following program.

**Note:** Please note that the following questions have been studied before posting this question:

1) [copying host memory to cuda __device__ variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325207/copying-host-memory-to-cuda-device-variable) 2) [Global variable in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255215/global-variable-in-cuda) 3) [Is there any way to dynamically allocate constant memory? CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635635/is-there-any-way-to-dynamically-allocate-constant-memory-cuda)

**So far, unsuccessful attempts have been made to:**

1. Dynamically allocate array of structs with `cudaMalloc()`, then
2. Use `cudaMemcpyToSymbol()` with the pointer returned from `cudaMalloc()` to copy to a `__device__` variable which can be used by the kernel.

**Code attempt:**

NBody.cu (error checking using **cudaStatus** has mostly been omitted for better readability, and function to read data from file into dynamic array removed):

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BLOCK 256

struct nbody {
    float x, y, vx, vy, m;
};
typedef struct nbody nbody;

// Global declarations
nbody* particle;

// Device variables
__device__ unsigned int d_N;  // Kernel can successfully access this
__device__ nbody d_particle;  // Update: part of problem was here with (*)

// Aim of kernel: to print contents of array of structs without using kernel argument
__global__ void step_cuda_v1() {
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    if (i < d_N) {
        printf("%.f\n", d_particle.x);
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned int N = 10;
    unsigned int I = 1;

    cudaMallocHost((void**)&particle, N * sizeof(nbody)); // Host allocation

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) particle[i].x = i;

    nbody* particle_buf; // device buffer
    cudaSetDevice(0);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&particle_buf, N * sizeof(nbody)); // Allocate device mem
    cudaMemcpy(particle_buf, particle, N * sizeof(nbody), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); // Copy data into device mem
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_particle, &particle_buf, sizeof(nbody*)); // Copy pointer to data into __device__ var
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_N, &N, sizeof(unsigned int)); // This works fine

    int NThreadBlock = (N + BLOCK - 1) / BLOCK;
    for (int iteration = 0; iteration <= I; iteration++) {

        step_cuda_v1 << <NThreadBlock, BLOCK >> > ();
        //step_cuda_v1 << <1, 5 >> > (particle_buf);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
        if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

"ERROR: kernel launch failed."

**Summary:**

- How can I print the contents of the array of structs from the kernel, without passing it as a kernel argument?
- Coding in C using VS2019 with CUDA 10.2

Comment: All those source arguments in the cudaMemcpy/cudaMemcpyToSymbol calls are wrong.except the one for N

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. What about them is incorrect?

Comment: they are pointers. Pass their values, not their address.....

Comment: I'm a little confused...the CUDA toolkit docs say under the params list for src to use "Source memory address". If you wouldn't mind, would you reply with the correct syntax please?

Comment: Also, `d_particle` is a pointer variable.  It holds a total of 8 bytes, which is supposed to be a pointer.  You cannot copy `N*sizeof(nbody)` to it.  Using a pointer variable as a `__device__` variable produces needless complication in your code (as you are now experiencing).  These changes are needed, at least: 1. `cudaMemcpy(particle_buf, particle, N * sizeof(nbody), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);`  2. `cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_particle, &particle_buf, sizeof(nbody*));`

Comment: The source address is the value. it is a pointer, its value is an address

Comment: by the way your posted code has various typos and will not compile, as-is.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions, I will try these and get back to you. @Robert Crovella , thanks for drawing my attention to the typos. I will address these and update the question accordingly.

Comment: So, following your syntactic change suggestions @RobertCrovella , I have updated the typos in the question and my kernel also now executes with no errors. However, the kernel output now consists only of zeros, whereas the output should mimic the contents of the input array. Do you think the `cudaMemcpy()` isn't copying the input data over correctly? Please let me know if this issue strays too far from my original question and requires a new SO question.

Comment: Your code that you have posted shows no initialization of the input array.  I'm not sure how you expect anything to be there or for me to comment on code that you have not shown.  Nevertheless, if after the allocation of space for the `particle` pointer (i.e. right before the call to `cudaSetDevice`), I insert this line of code:  `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) particle[i].x = i;` then I observe an output sequence that cycles from 0 to 9 repeatedly.  So I don't really see any issues.

Comment: That's strange- I have inserted the same `for` loop you have used, rebuilt the project, and yet continue to observe an output of all zeroes. I will attempt to troubleshoot this and write an update to the original question. Apologies for not providing the input array initialization code, it was quite substantial so I opted to leave it out.

Comment: In your edited code you have not done what I suggested.  Study the change #2 that I suggested *carefully*.

Comment: Hi @Robert Crovella, I have updated the edited code and still have the same unexpected output, having studied your change #2. Can you see where I am going wrong here? I really appreciate your help with this, so thank you.

Comment: In fact, I've found the error and have solved this issue. Thanks for both of your help. I will update with the solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Robert Crovella and @talonmies, here is the solution that outputs a sequence that cycles from 0 to 9 repeatedly.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BLOCK 256

//#include "Nbody.h"
struct nbody {
    float x, y, vx, vy, m;
};
typedef struct nbody nbody;

// Global declarations
nbody* particle;

// Device variables
__device__ unsigned int d_N;  // Kernel can successfully access this
__device__ nbody* d_particle;
//__device__ nbody d_particle;  // Update: part of problem was here with (*)

// Aim of kernel: to print contents of array of structs without using kernel argument
__global__ void step_cuda_v1() {
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    if (i < d_N) {
        printf("%.f\n", d_particle[i].x);
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned int N = 10;
    unsigned int I = 1;

    cudaMallocHost((void**)&particle, N * sizeof(nbody)); // Host allocation

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) particle[i].x = i;

    nbody* particle_buf; // device buffer
    cudaSetDevice(0);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&particle_buf, N * sizeof(nbody)); // Allocate device mem
    cudaMemcpy(particle_buf, particle, N * sizeof(nbody), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); // Copy data into device mem
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_particle, &particle_buf, sizeof(nbody*)); // Copy pointer to data into __device__ var
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_N, &N, sizeof(unsigned int)); // This works fine

    int NThreadBlock = (N + BLOCK - 1) / BLOCK;
    for (int iteration = 0; iteration <= I; iteration++) {

        step_cuda_v1 << <NThreadBlock, BLOCK >> > ();
        //step_cuda_v1 << <1, 5 >> > (particle_buf);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
        if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```